# Time aligning signals of different sampling rate with missing values

Tags: python, signal-processing, sensors

I am working with signals from two different sensors having different sampling rate one with 10 Hz and one with 1 Hz. I want to time align these two signals as the timing is bit different (in seconds). Also, there were chunks of values missing at random intervals from sensor with 1 Hz sampling rate.

I am purely from CS background and have never worked before on DSP. I would highly appreciate if you point me in right direction.

Comment: First you need to precisely define the technical. Only then can you consider asking for help on the part you don't know how to do.

Comment: I want to use these two signals as input to Machine learning classifier and they need to be of fixed length. I don't want to downsample the 10Hz signal as it will result in few training examples for the classifier.

Comment: Then you need to interpolate the 1 Hz signal.

Comment: but how ? I used singal.resample from scipy but it's making the signal smooth and the peaks that are in 1Hz signal are all lost.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to estimate an unknown function using samples taken at 1 Hz rate.

Simplest is just to use the previous sample as the estimated value.

First order linear draws a line through the two previous known values and uses the points on the line as the estimated values.  Whenever you get a new sample you replace the 2nd value with the first, and the first with the new value.  Keep track of the sample times also so that you can track properly across missing values.

If your samples are t1,v1,t2,v2 for times and values.  Current time is t.  Then estimated value will be

```
e = v1 + ((v2 - v1) * (t - t1) / ( t2 - t1))
```

Note that for t = t1 this evaluates to v1, and for t = t2 this evaluates to v2.